# Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data)

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, fine-uploader

i using the osclass script and when i want to upload picture as a normal user , i getting this error , the file upload work well but i cant see that picture in admin panel. any suggestion are welcomed. thanks.
->firebug report :

```
    [FineUploader 3.8.0] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data)
qq.log(a="[FineUploader 3.8.0] Err...umn 1 of the JSON data)", b="error")jquery.fineuploader.min.js (line 16)
qq.basePublicApi.log(a="Error when attempting to...umn 1 of the JSON data)", b="error")jquery.fineuploader.min.js (line 16)
qq.basePrivateApi._createUploadHandler/d.log(a="Error when attempting to...umn 1 of the JSON data)", b="error")jquery.fineuploader.min.js (line 16)
o()jquery.fineuploader.min.js (line 18)
s(a=0, b=Object { type="object"})jquery.fineuploader.min.js (line 18)
t/<()
```

and this is response :

```
    {"success":true,"uploadName":"auto_qqfile_57b1bb265d971.jpg"}
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-82144916-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

i've checked the fine uploader script and the source code is same as the original. so whats the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is returning invalid data. Fine uploader expects a valid JSON response, and, as you can see in the error message, that is not happening. You'll need to take a close look at your server code.

Comment: can you check my website with Team Viewer? i tried to review in 2 days and didnt found anything. i will be thankful if you help me.

Comment: fortunately i solved the problem. i just removed google analytics script and it began to work.Thanks to  Ray and Anthony.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your server should only return the JSON part :

```
{"success":true,"uploadName":"auto_qqfile_57b1bb265d971.jpg"}
```

It seems that a google analytics script is inserted after. That happens usually with Free hosting services.

Comment: im using paid hosting service . i tested a same uncostumized script and that uploader working fine . i just want to know how to  recover that uploader-related source code from original svript to my current script .just need a expert in osclass for helping me out.